# How to match ID between two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have, I guess a simple question but I cannot find the right answer. I have two pandas series (let's say "A" and "B") with ID in there (string). Series A is bigger than series B. What I am looking for is a way to have a resulting dataframe with 2 columns where the matching elements are on the same row and if there is a value in A that don't exist in B, to add a NaN

```
A            B
10368        10368
12567        NaN
13456        13456
...          ...
```

and so on.

I guess the merge function in pandas can be helpful but I could not manage to make it work

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with helper `Series` by index from values of `s2`:

```
df = pd.Series(s2.to_numpy(), index=s2).reindex(s1).rename_axis('A').reset_index(name='B')
```

Or [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) with left join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = s1.to_frame('A').merge(s2.to_frame('B'), left_on='A', right_on='B', how='left')
```